# WindowsPhone GridView Scroll inside ScrollView

Tags: gridview, windows-phone-8, scrollview

I have a gridview inside a ScrollView, XAML GUI, Windows Phone 8.1 Application

```
<ScrollView Margin="0,0,0,0">
<GridView x:Name="Test" Height="70" Margin="0,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"/>

</ScrollView>
```

The 'problem' is that i can scroll main activity but i can't scroll inside the gridview. How can i fix this?

Thakn you!

Comment: Have you tried without the ScrollView? GridView already supports scrolling, it's useless to set a ScrollView around a GridView.

Comment: it works without but i need it because the screen is small :)

Answer (score -1):

There will be a conflict with two ScrollView, 
1. ScrollView.
2. GridView's Scroll.

So, which doesn't work properly. Try to use one of the scroll.
You try to disable the GridView scroll.

Comment: suggestions and try must be included in comments